# How to get some part of text from a large text

Tags: php, string

Is there any way to get get a small part of data from an `array index` in php?
For example, I have an array of data like:

> Array(
>
> [title] => My title
>
> [description] =>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>      Code: No Promo Code Required
>      Begin: 2014-07-25 00:00:00
>       Expire: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
>
> [link] => http://google.com
>         )

from the above array's description index, i need the part only containing

> Code: No Promo Code Required
>   Begin: 2014-07-25 00:00:00
>   Expire: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Regardless of where ever this part occours in the text data.

Comment: there are many ways to do it, what have you tried already?

Comment: I tried `explode` but that's not what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myArray = array(
    "title" => "My Title",
    "description" => "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
Code: No Promo Code Required Begin: 2014-07-25 00:00:00 Expire: 0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "link" => "http://www.gopjn.com/t/3-79115-101746-99698"
    );

preg_match("/(Code.*Expire:\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/", $myArray["description"], $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/mWjau)

If there could be more than one instance of the string that you want to match, and you want to get all of them, use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.

Comment: I wish I could remember all the pretty regex off the top of my head. :) OP, something like this is a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most direct nor best way (regex would probably be a much better idea). But one way to do it:

```
$foo = explode('Code:', $myarray['description'], 1);
echo array_pop($foo);
```

Or perhaps:

```
$p = stripos($myarray['description'], 'Code:');
$foo = substr($myarray['description'], $p);
echo $foo;
```

Comment: are you sure about `1` as argument to explode? I suppose it should be `2`

Comment: honestly, not entirely off the top of my head. But limiting it to one match sounded like a good idea.

Comment: you will get only part before `Code:` in this way, but I suppose OP wants part after it

Comment: it is for only one match, i need it for the complete string, just want to cut that specific part of data from that string

Comment: Are you trying to remove that chunk from your description? Or are you trying to ONLY get the chunk?

Comment: @Lashane the limit may be incorrect, but pop should give the tail of the string, not the first part (that'd be shift).

Comment: @mable well as a matter of fact, i need to cut this chunk and then save this one in another index :)

Comment: well if you know it will ALWAYS be at the end, you could go the stripos route (make sure you start at zero and end at $p). Though a regex option will still be a better one, but it can make the same thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mb_substr()

echo mb_substr($myArray['description'], 0 /* that is the indent*/, 30 /*that is the count of elements which you want to show*/, 'utf-8' /*type of the coding*/);